# Appending data to PLIST - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4, plist

we need to be able to read in the contents of an existing plist file then add to the array / dictionary then write this new data to the plist file. The stricture is simple. We want multiple root keys as arrays and each with a few values. The structure looks like this,

```
124818240124810284.JPG          Array
                item 0          String     Some Attribute 1
                item 1          String     Some Attribute 2
```

So far we can create the above with no issue. But, as soon as we go to write another array to the plist the file is simply overwritten and all current contents are lost. What we need to do is read in the above and add to it so we get something like this,

```
124818240124810284.JPG          Array
                item 0          String     Some Attribute 1
                item 1          String     Some Attribute 2
354273577823597297.JPG          Array
                item 0          String     Some Attribute 1
                item 1          String     Some Attribute 2
```

And so on. We're at a loss and have been struggling with this for a day now. Please help where you can! Thanks in advance!!

We are currently writing this file as follows

```
NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Gallery.plist"];

// set the variables to the values in the text fields
NSMutableArray *myPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
[myPhotos addObject:@"NO"];
[myPhotos addObject:@"NO"];


// create dictionary with values in UITextFields
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray  arrayWithObjects: myPhotos, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.photoName, nil]];

NSString *error = nil;

// create NSData from dictionary
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

// check is plistData exists
if(plistData) {
    // write plistData to our Data.plist file
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}else{
        NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
        [error release];
}
```

The below is what we ended up with

```
NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Gallery.plist"];

// Get current content.
NSDictionary *oldContent = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
// Make a mutable copy.
NSMutableDictionary *newContent = [[oldContent mutableCopy] autorelease];
// Add new stuff.

NSMutableArray *myPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
[myPhotos addObject:@"Attribute 1"];
[myPhotos addObject:@"Attribute 2"];

[newContent setObject:myPhotos forKey:self.filePath];

// Now, write the plist:
[newContent writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: So, in essence you have trouble adding another entry to an array? Pseudo code: `array = [self readPlist]; array = [array arrayByAppendingObject:newEntry]; [self writePlist:array];` Is that what you want do?

Comment: Essentially yes but we're having trouble with the creation of the mutable array, addition of data to it then writing this out. I would like to post how we currently write the file if that would help

Comment: Yup, please edit your question and post the code that causes trouble.

Comment: Erm, you aren't even reading the original the original plist...

Comment: I've just posted the code we use to write the data to the plist. Again, this works perfectly. You can see the add a few objects then tell these objects to be linked with the key value of self.photoName. All is well, but, we need to read in the current list and add to it with some for of the above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
// Get current content.
NSDictionary *oldContent = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
// Make a mutable copy.
NSMutableDictionary *newContent = [[oldContent mutableCopy] autorelease];
// Add new stuff.
[newContent setObject:newObject forKey:newKey];
// Now, write the plist:
[newContent writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

There is no need to use `NSPropertyListSerialization` at all here.

Comment: This worked! I'll post in my question the code I ended up with to get this done. Thank you very much and everyone for the prompt replies!!

Answer (score -1):

You have a Dictionary to begin with,

```
124818240124810284.JPG //[valueForKey: 124818240124810284.JPG] 



                    item 0          String     Some Attribute 1 //[valueForKey:124818240124810284.JPG] valueForKey:Item 0];
                    item 1          String     Some Attribute 2 //[valueForKey:124818240124810284.JPG] valueForKey:Item 1];


    354273577823597297.JPG    //[valueForKey: 354273577823597297.JPG]    
                    item 0          String     Some Attribute 1 //[valueForKey: 354273577823597297.JPG] valueForKey:Item 0];
                    item 1          String     Some Attribute 2 //[valueForKey: 354273577823597297.JPG] valueForKey:Item 1;
```

And so on.....To add to it create a new dictionary with your new value/key pairs :

```
 NSMutableDictionary *newAttributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Attribute 0",@"Item 0",nil];
```

Make a new dictionary:

```
   NSMutableDictionary *newEntry = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:newAttributes,@"xxxxx.jpg", nil];//Makes a new dictionary
```

Or to append the data to the existing dictionary:

```
[dictionaryToAppend setValue:newAttribues ForKey:xxxxx.jpg"];
```