# How to Update an array created from a plist - error ReadOnly

Tags: iphone, arrays, ios5, multidimensional-array

I read a plist into memory and need to change one of the values if a user taps on a row.

I read the plist into memory and then show it on a table view.

This is the read into memory:

```
 self.questions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"q1" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Then I need to update one of the values, just while its in memory.  I guess I could make another whole array but it seems as though I  should be able to do something like this:

```
[[[self.questions valueForKey:title]  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Checked"] = @"1";
```

When run this I get an error saying the value is read only. Short on making another array to handle the checked off and on, is there a way to do this?

thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884215/appending-data-to-plist-iphone/8884515#8884515

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`+[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:options:format:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000942-SW5) to decode the contents of the file, and pass either the `NSPropertyListMutableContainers` option or the `NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves` option.

Comment: I am trying to change a value on the array that is already there.  See the 2nd example line on my question... How would I do that with your suggestion?

Comment: Use the `setValue:forKey:` method.

Comment: Sorry I am being really dense... where do I put the setvalue in this:      [[[self.questions valueForKey:title]  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  valueForKey:@"Checked" ] ;

Comment: You change `valueForKey:@"Checked"` to `setValue:@"1" forKey:@"Checked"`.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!  Eventually I will learn all of this!  I really do appreciate the extra effort!

Answer (score 1):

just use [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutabledictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for self.questions:

in *.h

```
NSMutableDictionary *questions;
```

in *.m

```
self.questions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"q1" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Comment: How do I assign a value to one of the fields in the dictionary?